# How to place query / other intensive logic in separate working thread BackGroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

For performance i have to replace DispatcherTimer with a BackGroundWorker to handle a intensive query that runs every 5 sec by using a Threading Timer.

I no longer get any result when implementing the following code, most of the times my application shuts down as well.

```
    public void CaculateTimeBetweenWegingen()
    {          
        if (listWegingen.Count > 1)
            msStilstand = (DateTime.Now - listWegingen[listWegingen.Count - 1]).TotalSeconds;

        if(msStilstand >= minKorteStilstand) 
        {
            stopWatch.Start(); 

            if (msStilstand >= minGroteStilstand)
            {
                FillDuurStilstandRegistrationBtn();

                if (zelfdeStilstand == false)
                {
                    CreateRegistrationButton();                       
                    zelfdeStilstand = true;
                }

                if (msStilstand <= maxGroteStilstand){
                    //....
                }
            }
        }
        else //new weging
        {
            if (stopWatch.IsRunning == true)
            {
                timerStilstand.Stop();

                stopWatch.Stop();

                //huidige registrationBtn
                if (GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Count > 1)
                {
                    GlobalObservableCol.regBtns[GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Count - 1].StopWatchActive = false;

                    GlobalObservableCol.regBtns[GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Count - 1].DuurStilstand =
                        String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", stopWatch.Elapsed.Hours, stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes, stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds);
                }

            }
            zelfdeStilstand = false;
        }
    }/*CaculateTimeBetweenWegingen*/


public void CreateRegistrationButton()
    {
        InitializeDispatcherTimerStilstand();

        RegistrationButton btn = new RegistrationButton(GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Count.ToString());
        btn.RegistrationCount = GlobalObservableCol.regBtnCount;
        btn.Title = "btnRegistration" + GlobalObservableCol.regBtnCount;
        btn.BeginStilstand = btn.Time;

        GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Add(btn);
        GlobalObservableCol.regBtnCount++;

        btn.DuurStilstand = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", 0, 0, 0);         
    }


public void InitializeDispatcherTimerWeging()
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        TimerCallback callback = MyTimerCallBack;
        timerWegingen = new Timer(callback);

        timerWegingen.Change(0, 5000);
    }

public void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }


    private void MyTimerCallBack(object state)
    {
        DisplayWegingInfo();
        CaculateTimeBetweenWegingen();
    }
```

*The button gets refilled with new values every 1 sec trough a other timer. "DuurStilstand" is a dependency property*

```
    private void FillDuurStilstandRegistrationBtn()
    {
        TimeSpan tsSec = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds);
        TimeSpan tsMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes);
        TimeSpan tsHour = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(stopWatch.Elapsed.Hours);

        if (GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Count >= 1
                    && GlobalObservableCol.regBtns[GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Count - 1].StopWatchActive == true)
        {
            GlobalObservableCol.regBtns[GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Count - 1].DuurStilstand =
                            String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", tsHour.Hours, tsMin.Minutes, tsSec.Seconds);
        }
    }
```

All the above code is written in a separate c# class.

How exactly do i make this code work with BackGroundWorker and how / where to update the GUI with Dispatcher/Invoke. Been trying for a long while and i cannot seem to solve this issue atm.

I have also seen that the Complete method of the BackGroundWorker can be used to update the GUI, but not sure how exactly. The buttons get created and saved in a ObservableCollection.

```
 public static ObservableCollection<RegistrationButton> regBtns = new ObservableCollection<RegistrationButton>();
```

Some examples would be most useful. Since i know more or less what has to been done but not exactly sure how to implement it.

Best Regards,
Jackz

Comment: You posted your old code and not the changes you made to run the *query* on a background worker.  Sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the meaning of your app but you'll be able to update UI like this

```
public void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() =>
        {
            //do your stuff
        }));
    }
```

Maybe the Rendering event should help you to deal with the UIThread.

```
CompositionTarget.Rendering += (s, args) =>
        {
            //do your stuff
        };
```

Hope it help